# Phing build.xml in SVN and local build

Tags: phing

I am developing in windows environment and my production server has linux. My goal was updating production version from my local machine, but run in to problems with windows&ssh.

So now my backup plan is just doing it locally on my server and that is ok. This allows me to do it easily via ssh from different workstations.

What I am now wondering is my build.xml file, which is included with my project in svn. Do I really need to make initial export just to run my build.xml which then does actual build? Or should I just separate my build.xml from app? How this kind of local build should be done?

Comment: you should close this question or post a bounty it will improve the chances that additional questions will be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the build file with the app for portability, future proofing and versioning reasons. I also would keep the svn export step it ensures a clean and consistent state to run your build from.

Comment: You may also want to post a question regarding your win/ssh issue.